# How to Send SSL Packets captured with Wireshark?

Tags: c#, networking, ssl, wireshark

I currently have some SSL packets captured with Wireshark, and I want to know how can I send them to a certain IP address using C#.

The problem is that C# has no native support for SSL packets, so I can't do it without a certain library.

I don't want to modify the packet at all, just send it after I captured it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Replaying SSL is impossible, so sending them will do nothing.

Comment: C# has no support at all for networking.

Comment: @JohnSaunders C# does have a support for networking (You can make a DoS program with C# for example). Jon, I tried to do that to see if I can do something with some chat messages that are SSL encrypted. Is there nothing to do about that? Can't I decrypt the packets themselves?

Comment: @Jon I don't think there's a better answer to the question than your comment.

Comment: C# has no support at all for networking. The .NET Framework has support for networking.

Comment: Learn the difference between the chicken and the nest.

Comment: @BlueRay010: Assuming no insider information, you can decrypt those packets as much as I can decrypt the SSL traffic between you and your bank.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: I added an answer, thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third parties with no access to the internal state of the software communicating through SSL cannot do much that is meaningful with the captured packets.

You can derive some information regarding the length of the data being passed around, but you cannot decrypt it (of course) and you cannot replay it (SSL has built-in protection against replay attacks).

Sorry, but it seems you are out of luck.